# Binding List to ComboBox in VB.Net WPF Application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` on a VB.Net WPF application.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Server.RecipeList()}" DisplayMemberPath="RecipeID" SelectedValuePath="RecipeID"/>
```

In the code-behind, I have a class variable called Server:

```
Public Server As BatchServer = New BatchServer
```

In my Server object, I have a `List`:

```
Private mRecipeList As New List(Of Recipe)
```

And my default constructor for the Server is

```
Public Sub New()
    Server = New BatchRemote.RemoteSupport
    PopulateRecipeList()
End Sub
```

I want to bind this `List` to the `ComboBox`, so it should display the RecipeID of each Recipe in my List. My data-binding looks as it does in the first code block, but when I run the application the `ComboBox` is always empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to declare `Server` as a `public Property` *that correctly implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)*. Then you need to do the same for `RecipeList`. Then you should be able to `Bind` like this:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Server.RecipeList}" DisplayMemberPath="RecipeID"
SelectedValuePath="RecipeID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't work because you're binding to a simple list, and so the property isnt updated when you add or remove some list element for example.

Declare the auxiliar list as an ObservableCollection [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) in the window and binding to the combo like:

```
Private Property auxRecipeList As New ObservableCollection(Of Recipe)
```

then in the xaml do the binding like this:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding auxRecipeList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourcetrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="RecipeID" SelectedValuePath="RecipeID"/>
```